# Sliding animation while adding showing layout

Tags: android, sliding

I want to show/hide a layout but with adding a sliding effect while it's appearing and hiding
but i'm bound to min SDK 8 to cover as much devices as possible , how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use animations like slide out, slide in in combination with alpha. A simple example If I am correct about getting your question could be Gallery's header and footer animation.
Clicking on the image shows the header and footer with sliding effect and showing and hiding the views.

**Slide animation out bottom**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >

    <!-- Slide in is basically view coming in from some outside area, in this case bottom -->
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

You can change the value and achieve the slide animation. If required I can assist you in getting the other slide animation or you can google it.

Comment: Thanks alot ! :) dunno why i was getting my head stuck on doing it from code :)